# git ssh store password

Tags: git, msysgit

I am using GIT via SSH using password-based auth (publickey is not supported due to server-side encryption that uses user password as encryption key).

Is it possible to store the password locally somehow so that I don't have to enter it every time?

So far I tried:

- putting the password in the URL, didn't work
- putting the machine, username and password into _netrc, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are very few options available if you can't use public key auth.

If you can leave an SSH session open to the git server, using the -M flag, you can edit your ssh_config to specify the ControlPath and ControlMaster values. This will prompt you to manually log on, but this would tunnel all future ssh connections through the master connection. (See: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5)

This **may** work for git. I haven't tested it.